# Properties embedded within another object

Tags: c#, wcf, reportviewer

I am trying to use a business object that I am passing to the report.rdlc. The properties in my object are not directly exposed. The properties I require are embedded within another object inside the top level object. As this is a WCF project I can't control what goes on at the server end. I am just able to request these objects or Insert/Update/Delete their info from the database. It is done in this way as the back end can use multiple flavors of database.

Here is what I can see after adding my business object as a `DataSource`:

```
-BusinessObject
 -CustomerInfo
  -ClientName
    -ColumnName
    -DisplayName
    -FieldName
    -IsNull
    -KeyColumn
    -SenondKeyColumn
    -StringValue 
  -ClientID
    -ColumnName
    -DisplayName
    -FieldName
    -IntValue
    -IsNull
    -KeyColumn
    -SenondKeyColumn
   +ClientAddress
   +Instrument
   +Telephone
```

etc etc

I need to be able to display, for example, the `ClientName.StringValue` field.
If I drag the field I want onto the report I get:

```
=First(Fields!StringValue.Value)
```

This doesn't display anything when the report is run, I assume because it can't qualify what `StringValue` it is talking about and there could be many.

If I try dragging the `ClientName` object I get:

```
=First(Fields!ContactName.Value)
```

However this gives:

```
#ERROR
```

When the report is run.

I would have thought you could use:

```
=First(Fields!ClientName.StringValue.Value)
```

but this won't even let me build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the info wasn't at the root level. I worked it out though.

```
=First(Fields!ClientName.Value.StringValue, "BusinessObject_CustomerInfo")
```

I've got a pretty good grip of the ReportViewer component now cheers.

Comment: Will someone please make this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the data source to the CustomerInfo instance (or list) returned from the service it should work. The ReportViewer control can be a little complicated when you start dealing with object hierarchies, but you don't have to do anything crazy or special if all the information is at the root level.